# HTML relative paths issue for script src

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with a website I built from angular. In `index.html`, there are references to javascript files, but my problem is this: in the HTML, the paths are relative to the file but the browser looks for the files in the root dir:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RasaBE</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This works fine when everything is in the root folder of my website, but I wanted to have everything in a subfolder `/bo/`. So `index.html` is in `localhost/bo/index.html` and so are all the scripts. Since it's a relative path in the code I'd expect my browser to look for `localhost/bo/script.js`, but instead it looks for `localhost/script.js`.

A screenshot to show what's wrong:

[image: it doesn't look for the file in the right dir]

I tested this in Chrome and I have the same issue. It's a bit complicated to change the paths directly since it's compiled from angular, and I'd probably have to change it every time it compiles. Is this an issue with Firefox and the way it deals with relative paths?

I should also add that `host/bo/inline.bundle.js` exists and can be found by the browser but the it looks for it in the root folder instead of the same folder as `index.html`.

Comment: Can you adding "/" before js name to make it relative.<script type="text/javascript" src="/inline.bundle.js"></script>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "base" element sets the default location for the page.

**Remove**

```
<base href="/">
```

**OR**

```
<base href="/bo/">
```

Comment: I can't remove it, because it's necessary in other parts of the angular code apparently (I didn't write it, I'm setting it up), but changing it to /bo/ worked well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your Angular Webapp run from every subfolder without touching the code

**Change**

```
<base href="/">
```

**To**

```
<base href=".">
```

Removing the "base" element won't work since Angular throws then an error complaining about the missing element.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was all because of the  tag that is added by angular, editing it to `<base href="/bo/">` makes it work. since it's just one line to change I consider it fixed.